# Set the LineTraceByChannel to use my custom created channel? C++

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I want to use LineTraceSingleByChannel function for my SightRay component which will be used for my adventure game. I want to mark certain objects in game as 'Viewable' in Trace Channel. Then the ray will only be true if it hits a 'Viewable' object.

I have created the Viewable trace channel in the Collision settings of Project Settings. But I have two problems now.

1. In the actual c++ code I am writing, how do I reference this new 'Viewable' channel in the ECollisionChannel parameter of the method?
2. How do I assign this channel to each object in the scene?

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, I've read many Unreal documentation pages and forum threads but can't get a straight answer, particularly without using Blueprint nodes.

Here is my code:

```
bool USightRay::GetLineTraceHit(FHitResult &OutHit)
{

FVector LineStart = UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCameraManager(this, 0)->GetCameraLocation();
FVector LineEnd = LineStart + UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCameraManager(this, 0)->GetCameraRotation().Vector() * LineTraceLength;
//ECollisionChannel viewable =  WHAT CAN I PUT HERE?????
if (GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(OutHit, LineStart, LineEnd, viewable))
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("HIT ME WITH YOUR RHYTHM STICK!"));
    return true;
}


return false;
}
```

I actually thought this would be simple before I started to code it. I've used it before but I just used ECollisionChannel::ECC_Visibility  in place of 'viewable'. This time I want to learn to filter the collisions and traces properly.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Well I kind of figured it out, but thought I can post here for any comments in case I am doing anything wrong. Also this might help someone who reads this with same problem.

Basically, I had created the custom trace as  mentioned, but I didn't really know how to access it in code. After hours of reading I found you must go to your projects DefaultEngine.ini file , in there search "ECC" and it will tell you which one it is.

Then you can put something like:

```
#define COLLISION_VIEWABLE ECC_GameTraceChannel2
```

at top of your cpp file, and in the method parameter use ECollisionChannel::COLLISION_VIEWABLE  , this now raycasts only on my specified channel.

Comment: This is the right way!

Comment: I saw this post when I was searching for reason why tracing by custom channel doesn't work. I thought that maybe the channel name defined by the macro must follow COLLISION_NAME pattern, it cannot be an arbitrary name. But I found that's not the point, you can define it as anything you want. There are EngineTraceChannel and GameTraceChannel in the ECC enum, I set the Engine one by mistake. Thank you 